# Sphinx 1.8 Typerror Metaclass conflict , Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-sphinx, metaclass

I am working with sphinx 1.8 document generation for my project in python 2.7.
I have a class inheriting three classes:

```
class Meta(type(QtGui.QWidget), type(BaseClass)):
    pass

class UI(QWidget, BaseClass, BaseWidget)
    __metaclass__ = Meta

    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        BaseClass.__init__(self)
        BaseWidget.__init__(self)
```

There is no error in Python application.

But with ***sphinx 1.8***, the following error is generated:
**TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases**.

Could anyone please help with this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with Sphinx using Python 3 instead of Python 2.7.
I have the other project running in Python 3.
To solve the error force Sphinx to use Python 2.7 version.
In **make.bat** file :
remove if statement and set the SPHINXBUILD path explicitly:

```
@ECHO OFF

pushd %~dp0

REM Command file for Sphinx documentation

set SPHINXBUILD= "C:\\Python27\\Scripts\\sphinx-build.exe"

set SOURCEDIR=.
set BUILDDIR=_build
```

It will not give the metaclass erro anymore.